# How do I remove the non-numeric character from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string. What is the regular expression to split the numbers into the array?

Comment: 1. Post a String example

2. Is a String or an Array or an Array of Strings (String[])?

2. What you want?

just remove the non-numeric character from a String or remove it and get an Array containing the numbers

Comment: Please make this question clearer.  Some pointers: 

Show String input and String output.

Reword the second sentence to make it a little more explanatory.  Do you have multiple numbers separated by a non-digit?  Or each digit should be split?

Comment: Take a look at [https://regexr.com/] please. You'll be able to try out any regex and see a break down of what each part of the regex does, as well as "self-learn" how to use and work with regex expressions by playing around with different regex in this website. hope it helps Cheers!

Answer (score 148):

Are you removing or splitting? This will remove all the non-numeric characters.

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" )
```

Comment: `myStr = myStr.replaceAll("[\\D]", "");`

Comment: Without-square-brackets version: `myStr.replaceAll("\\D+", "")`, maybe more readable.

Answer (score 32):

One more approach for removing all non-numeric characters from a string:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Answer (score 20):

```
String str= "somestring";
String[] values = str.split("\\D+");
```

Comment: Yours is the best answer compared to all the others.  Straight to the point.

Answer (score 15):

Another regex solution:

```
string.replace(/\D/g,'');  //remove the non-Numeric
```

Similarly, you can

```
string.replace(/\W/g,'');  //remove the non-alphaNumeric
```

In RegEX, the symbol '\' would make the letter following it a template: **\w** -- *alphanumeric*, and **\W** - *Non-AlphaNumeric*, negates when you **capitalize** the letter.

Comment: Yes, this is javascript code, not JAVA.  eveliotc's answer is in JAVA. (See a couple of answers down)

Answer (score 8):

You will want to use the String class' [Split()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method and pass in a regular expression of "\D+" which will match at least one non-number.

```
myString.split("\\D+");
```

Comment: This will remove all the numeric characters and give an array with all the non-numeric ones. It's exactly the opposite of the requested.

Comment: Whoops, I must have misinterpreted what the question was. In that case it would be the negated version of the regex, which is \\D+

I will update my answer!

Answer (score 3):

[Java 8 collection streams](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/streams.html) :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
test.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).filter(Character::isDigit).forEach(sb::append);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in Flex SDK 4.14.0

myString.replace(/[^0-9&&^.]/g, "");

Answer (score 1):

you could use a recursive method like below:

```
public static String getAllNumbersFromString(String input) {
        if (input == null || input.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        char c = input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
        String newinput = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1);

            if (c >= '0' && c<= '9') {
            return getAllNumbersFromString(newinput) + c;

        } else {
            return getAllNumbersFromString(newinput);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a good exercise practicing using "Recursive".  But in the real world (programming world), programmers would use RegEX!!  RegEX has been around for half a century.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers will strip your decimal point. If you want to **save your decima**l, you might want to

```
String str = "My values are : 900.00, 700.00, 650.50";

String[] values = str.split("[^\\d.?\\d]"); 
// split on wherever they are not digits except the '.' decimal point
// values: { "900.00", "700.00", "650.50"}
```

Comment: Why do you put `\\d` twice in the character class? `[^\\d.?\\d]` is a negated character class that matches any character that is not digit, dot or question mark.

Comment: Toto, my solution above is designated to save the decimal point on splitting for values such as "900.50" -- you don't want to have them split into {"900", "50"}

Comment: Well, then `[^\\d.]` is enough and does the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way without using Regex:**

```
public static String getOnlyNumerics(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            strBuff.append(c);
        }
    }
    return strBuff.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your code is NOT SIMPLE!   You should use RegEX.  RegEX is a powerful tool that simplifies a lot of code, you need to get a grip on RegEX and USE it.