# Transform a text case in to UpperCase Using JavaFX CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

Any one can help me to Change the Case in JavaFX project I'm trying to find solution by browse, But i can't Please find the below code I'm trying but it can't get the result

```
.text {
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-font-size: 24;
    -fx-text-fill: #263248;
    -fx-padding: 10 20 10 20;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-text-transform: uppercase; /* this property is not working */ 
}
```

**Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks!**

Comment: Is `-fx-text-transform` a JavaFX css property? I don't think so.

Comment: I already commented and i need solution for that line alone... what is the exact code for that?

Comment: You cannot achieve what you are trying to, using CSS. You need to do it in Java code.

Comment: FXML only support javaFX CSS

Comment: You can always assign a controller to a FXML and make the necessary code arrangement inside the `initialize(..)`. For more information, go through [Mastering FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/)

Comment: I need one liner code.... to fix my issue... FXML is not my issue...?

Comment: Then add a listener to your control and use the method `toUpperCase()`. A simple example is [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884812/javafx-textfield-automatically-transform-text-to-uppercase/30885096#30885096)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no CSS property that handles text transformation in JavaFX (currently none, see the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)). But you can actually do it in Java with just a single line of code!

For an instance, you have a `Label` node which has an ID named `label`.

```
<Label fx:id="label" text="Hello!" />
```

In this case, you can reference the `node` by its ID and set its text `toUpperCase()` with a controller class.

```
// Reference to the node you wish
// to transform texts to uppercase.
@FXML private Label label;

@Override
// Assuming you have Initializable class implemented.
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

  // Get the current text value of the node.
  String text = label.getText();

  // Then update the text into whatever case you like.
  label.setText(text.toUpperCase());

}
```

**OR**

Simply straight from a Java code (one straight line of code).

```
Label label = new Label("Hello!".toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Thank you for your time will check!

Answer (score 1):

**This is a universal way.**
You can mark what you need as `upper` and `lower` in `styleClass` and call this method:

```
public static void textTransform(@NotNull Node root) {
    _textTransform(root, ".upper");
    _textTransform(root, ".lower");
}
private static void _textTransform(@NotNull Node root, @NotNull String selector) {
    boolean upper = selector.equalsIgnoreCase(".upper");
    for (Node node : root.lookupAll(selector)) {
        if (node instanceof Text) {
            Text text = (Text) node;
            text.setText(upper ? text.getText().toUpperCase() : text.getText().toLowerCase());
        } else
        if (node instanceof Label) {
            Label label = (Label) node;
            label.setText(upper ? label.getText().toUpperCase() : label.getText().toLowerCase());
        } else
        if (node instanceof Button) {
            Button button = (Button) node;
            button.setText(upper ? button.getText().toUpperCase() : button.getText().toLowerCase());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add ChangeListener to Text:

```
Text text;
//...
text.textProperty().add(
    (observer, oldValue, newValue) -> text.setText(newValue.toUpperCase())
);
```