# JavaFX TextField cancelEdit not working as expected

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a [`TextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) and I would like the contents of the field to be restored to their previous value when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> which is expected behaviour on most systems (I have no idea why JavaFX doesn't do this by default).

To this end I tried to use [`TextField.cancelEdit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#cancelEdit--) but it appears that this is doing nothing.

Here is a SSCCE

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UiTest2Controller extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage aPrimaryStage) throws Exception {
        final TextField field = new TextField();
        field.setOnAction(aEvent -> {
            System.out.println("Action");
        });
        field.setOnKeyPressed(aEvent -> {
            if (aEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                System.out.println("Escape");
                field.cancelEdit();
                field.getParent().requestFocus();
            }
        });
        field.setPromptText("Hello World...");

        aPrimaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(field)));
        aPrimaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type something in the text field
2. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

**Expected behaviour:** The field returns to previous value (empty first time) and focus is lost.

**Actual behaviour:** The fiels retains its value at the time and focus is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the specifics, but it seems to work as expected if the `TextField` has a `TextFormatter` assigned:

```
field.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER));
```

Comment: Yes, I just found this out by looking in the Java FX source. That is so under-documented... Also with text formatter set Escape cancels the edit by default.

Comment: Beside, you can call `field.commitValue()` to create the "restore point", otherwise it will always roll back the value to an empty string.

Comment: calling `field.commitValue()` without a `TextFormatter` has no effect on the outcome.   

With `TextFormatter`, it works as expected without calling `commitValue`, so I'm not sure if it's required.