# Filter string as decimal number

Tags: android, regex

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372905/3058015) is a nice short example to filter string as decimal:

```
String str = "a12.334tyz.78x";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

, which makes `12.334.78`

But how to filter this second decimal part? I have a string `valued 12345.67 doll.` (notice the dot at the end). So i need only `12345.67`

Sorry for not just commenting that Óscar López's answer because have not enough reputation.

Comment: Two numbers can be extracted from `12.334.78`. 12.344 and .78 is that what you need?

Comment: sln, no. A string can be of any kind, the given one is just for example. The thing is i have to get only one dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to remove any `.` that does not precede a digit.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]|\\.(?!\\d)", "");
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Dlb3cS)

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up but not sure. Android regex (like Java) can use the
`\G` assertion, which means start at the end of the last match position.

Your problem can't be solved with a single regex, however it can be done  with
two regex.

It's simple really.

Both are used in a replace all situation.

The first just clears out whatever you don't  want.
Using your example its.

Find:  `"[^\\d.]+"`
Replace:  `""`

The second is:
Find:  `"(?:(?!\\A)\\G|(\\.))([^.]*)\\."`
Replace: `"$1$2"`

The last regex removes all the Dots after the first one (but *NOT* the first one)
Here is the breakdown of this regex:

```
 (?:
      (?! \A )             # Not at BOS
      \G                   # Start at end of last match position
   |                     # or, 
      ( \. )               # (1), One time, The first Dot in the string
 )
 ( [^.]* )            # (2), Optional any chars
 \.                   # Until we find the next extra Dot to remove
```

Input:

```
a12.334tyz.78x
```

Output:

```
12.33478
```