# How to convert "abcd1234" to int 1234

Tags: java

```
public class testcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int c;
         String test = "ABCD1234";

    }
}
```

How can I convert from `String test` to `int c` and the answer is `1234`?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Strip off the non-digits, then parse the digits.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters

Answer (score 0):

convert int to string with `int c = Integer.parseInt(str);`

Comment: This will throw an error as the string is not started with digits.