# parseDouble exception on Android while parsing a valid Double value

Tags: java, android, parsing, double

The following code

```
if (Double.parseDouble(value) > 0)
```

throws the following exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "‎-2.49"

The logged value seems like a valid Double, what might cause this exception?

Comment: It seems like your string is valid. Maybe there is an invisible character in it, try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters) to clean it up and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You seem to encounter a locale issue.
That is, integer and fractional part separators differ in different locales, somewhere it's `.` and somewhere `,`.

See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator), there's a probable solution.
Use the locale which fits the best for you, for example `Locale.US` uses `.` as the separator.