# Getting Number format exception

Tags: java

I am getting number format exception, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int v = 1476423;
    double d = v;
    System.out.println("Double "+v);
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println("String "+s);
    v = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("Integer "+v);
}
```

When I am trying to print v, it is giving number format exception. Can somebody help here?

**Error:**

```
Double 1476423
String 1476423.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1476423.0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at testCases.Random.main(Random.java:12)
```

Comment: You can't parse a floating point number to an Integer

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly not an integer value, it *has* a decimal part, even though it's zero:

```
"1476423.0"
```

Either do this:

```
int v = Integer.parseInt("1476423");
```

Or this:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("1476423.0");
```

Comment: i was just trying other stuff, actually the problem is I am getting a `string` with a `.` so I wanted to convert it into `int` and remove the `.0`

Comment: Then remove it, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10372905/201359

Comment: If the above answered your question, please don't forget to accept it, just click on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by deleting this line

```
v = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

But the problem is that `double d = v;` makes `v` a floating point number, which you convert to a string, then try to convert back to an int, which is not very clear why you do that because you aren't changing the value of `v` in any way.

Comment: i was just trying other stuff, actually the problem is I am getting a `string` with a `.` so I wanted to convert it into `int` and remove the `.0`

Comment: Yes, a string representation of a floating point number (in other words, a decimal) cannot be parsed to an int because integers do not contain decimals