# Java (String Variable).replaceAll() argument \\D with exceptions?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to read through a user input string that removes all nondigit characters excluding some characters like +,-,/,. etc. This is for a calculator. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to split the initial string beforehand.

Comment: `String.replaceAll()` takes a [Regex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression); write an expression that does what you need. For example `[^0-9+/,.-]`.

Comment: You need to provide examples with explicit requirements. So far it seems like a simple regex is fine, with the caveat that it'd likely just be easier to parse it for real, since you'll need to do that anyway to create the calculation part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String remove all non numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Add any characters you want to keep inside the `[ ]`

```
string.replaceAll("[^0-9+-]", "");
```

When you use `^` inside `[]`, it will match any character that is NOT in `[]` (excluding the `^`).

In this case, it will match any character that is not a number (from 0 to 9), not a `+`, and not a `-`.