# NumberFormatException: Invalid int even if it is really an integer

Tags: java, string, parsing, int, number-formatting

I encounter some problems parsing a string into integer, I don't know what the problem is.

I am passing a string with an integer value to my function to check if it would be parseable.

This is my function.

```
private boolean isNumeric (String value){
        try {
            System.out.println("VALUE = " +value);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(value);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I checked it by printing into the console. here is the result.

```
I/System.out: VALUE = 77
    NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "77"
```

Can you guys help me figure out what is wrong here. Cause I cannot convert this string into an integer.

Comment: Are there non-printable characters in the string?

Comment: To prove Andy's intuition try and print `value.length()`. If it is more than 2 he's right.

Comment: no sir, it's just numbers, as you can see in the result, I printed it to check for additional characters, but there is none.

Comment: @renoroysorima what part of *non-printable* makes you think that printing would show them? :)

Comment: @renoroysorima "as you can see" printing a string with non-printable characters won't show you the non-printable characters.

Comment: This code works fine when passed "77". Your problem isn't reproducible.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri it's probably because that's not the value he's passing.

Comment: Then he might want to debug and print whatever he's passing first.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the lenght becomes 3. if so, what is the best way to remove it ?

Comment: Try to print each character of the input string and see it yourself.

Comment: @renoroysorima you can remove [everything but the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618873/133203) (adapt that by ignoring the part that accepts decimal separators, for your case). But you may want to discover why there's a non-printable character in that string to begin with. I suppose that string comes from an external source?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri that won't really help with non printable characters.

Comment: I already figured it out, Thanks to @KremKlatt. all I needed is to trim the non visible white space. Thank you for you answers guys, it really helps me a lot.

Comment: I wonder how escape characters ended up in argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this as this will trim out all whitespaces from your input:

```
private boolean isNumeric (String value){
        try {
            System.out.println("VALUE = " +value);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(value.trim());
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`parseInt()` should return a NumberFormatException if the string is not parseable, but "77" should be. You should therefore try to trim it before you parse it to an int, maybe that would help.

Comment: Thanks bro. There was a non visible white space in this strings. so I needed to trim those white spaces to make it a number.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)