# Strip non-numerical characters from String

Tags: java, android, string

I Have string like so: `"He3llo5"`

How do I strip this String so that only the numbers remain?

Desired result:

```
35
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. The [alleged duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10372862/642706) involves a decimal separator. This question is simpler, integers, no decimal separator involved. This Question here probably *is* a duplicate, but not of that particular Question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Pattern Example

```html
    Pattern intsOnly=Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher make=intsOnly.matcher(string);
        make.find();
        string=make.group();
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  In the OP's example, it will give you `"3"` not `"35"` as required.

Comment: The **code in the Answer fails**, as [commented by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376943/strip-non-numerical-characters-from-string/67376973#comment119093300_67376971). See the [code execute at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/U9vzH6), producing `3` rather than `35`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: use a regex and `.replaceAll()`:

```
String string="He3llo5";
String result = string.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

See this [code execute at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/EQAwYq).

> 35

Alternatively, you could write your own method which utilizes `Character.isDigit()` and a `StringBuilder` like so:

```
public static String stripAlphabet(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        str.append(Character.isDigit(c) ? c : "");
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

The following also produces `35` as the result:

```
String string="He3llo5";
String result = stripAlphabet(string);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I use the Pattern  and it, s works fine and I use Replace  and also work so which is the best to use

Comment: @Nelson I would suggest using `.replaceAll()` - it's only 1 line of code, and is the easiest to understand.

Comment: and what is the best?

Comment: It depends on your criteria for "best"-ness.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```java
Integer.parseInt(
        "He3ll5"
                .codePoints()
                .filter( Character :: isDigit )
                .collect(
                        StringBuilder :: new ,
                        StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint ,
                        StringBuilder :: append
                )
                .toString()
)
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/EPp3xt).

> 35

## Loop code points

Loop through each character’s Unicode code point number, asking if that code point represents a character that is a digit. If so, collect that code point or its conversion to a `String`.

Calling [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) gives us an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), a stream of the code point integer numbers.

We filter out the letters by calling [`Character#IsDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(int)). We collect the remaining digit characters into a `StringBuilder`.

From the string of digits, we parse as an `int` by calling [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

```java
String input = "He3llo5";

IntStream codePoints = input.codePoints();
String digits =
        codePoints
                .filter( Character :: isDigit )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new ,
                        StringBuilder :: appendCodePoint ,
                        StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
int result = Integer.parseInt( digits );
```

> result = 35

### Avoid `char`

Be aware that the `char` type in Java is obsolete. That type fails to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Use code point integers instead of `char`.