# How to convert data value?

Tags: java, string, kotlin

So far I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I want to change a value.

So can convert value from $5,000,000 to 5000000 in java/kotlin?

Comment: I retrieve the data using jsoup/scraping, the data is a combination of several characters ($5,000,000).
  and I want to change it to 5000000 so that it can be formulated later.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\D", "")` will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "personal" approach is to try and figure out how you got the input in the in the first place.  In this case, from Java, you'd probably use a `NumberFormatter` to format a numerical value to a `String`, so you might want to consider reversing it.

```
String text = "$5,000,000";
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Number number = formatter.parse(text);
System.out.println(number.intValue());
```

Will print `5000000`

Now, this will assume that the `Locale` the JVM is using makes use of `$` and not say, pounds or yen, but you can seed the `Locale` when you call `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`, so that's one level of customisation you have.

Of course, you could just drop back to `"$5,000,000".replace("$", "").replace(",", "")` and then parse the result to an `int`, but I'm not a massive fan of it, but I'm peculiar that way

Comment: oh sorry, how about 5,000,000 to 5000000 without $?

Comment: i use
`val number = (text).replace(",", "")
                         println(number.toInt())
                         iShowLog("number: $number")`
but the result stuck

Comment: i change from     val number = (text).replace(",", "")
to     val number = text.replace(",", "")
and resolved, thanks

Comment: You could consider generating a white/black list instead, such as "remove all non-numerical characters", something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-but-keep-the-decimal-separator) for example.  But it depends on your needs