# java lang number format exception error For input string: "7500000

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Below is the code I have written

```
List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Below loop for converting string to int and adding to list.
for (int in = 0; in < count; in++) {
        String str = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)                                           
        .executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", AllCardPrice.get(in)).toString().trim();
        String str1 = str.replace("$", "").replace(",", "").trim();
        System.out.println("Amount on card " + AllCardPrice.get(in).getText());
        if (!str1.equals("")) {
           int priceoncard = Integer.parseInt(str1);
           ar.add(priceoncard);
        }
   }
```

I am getting following console error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7500000
                        <!---->"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Numbers don't start with `"`, or contain newlines or spaces, or contain `<!---->`.

Comment: Try `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - IIRC, the double quotes are not part of the string that was being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do string sanitization to remove all non-digit characters from the input string, as well as put a try-catch block around the code so that each input is handled separately :)

```
List<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int in = 0; in < count; in++) {
        String str = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)                                           
        .executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", AllCardPrice.get(in)).toString().trim();
        //remove any NON-numeric values: 
        String str1 = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        System.out.println("Amount on card " + AllCardPrice.get(in).getText());
        //Add a try-catch block:
        try{
            if (!str1.equals("")) {
               int priceoncard = Integer.parseInt(str1);
               ar.add(priceoncard);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Oh no, caught an exception!");
        }
   }
```

Non-numeric code removal reference: [Java String remove all non numeric characters but keep the decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-but-keep-the-decimal-separator)

Comment: `"[^\\d]"` may be `"\\D"`.

Comment: Note also that this would cause `123 hello world 456` to be parsed as `123456`, that is, conflating the two groups of numbers.